# Reorder Octates in an IPAddressees / Java

Tags: java, string, ip-address

I have ip address example "27.96.168.92" and would like to reorder the each Octates in the ip address. so the output should be "92.168.96.27".

I can achieve this with string split functionality.
Is there any way to achieve this without split functionality of java string,
something like load it to char array and then loop ?

Actual ip : "27.96.168.92"
expected ip : "92.168.96.27"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple regular expression:

```
String ip = "27.96.168.92";
String switched = ip.replaceAll("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)", "$4.$3.$2.$1");
System.out.println(switched);
```

Output:

```
92.168.96.27
```

Because you're only switching numbers around, you shouldn't require a regex pattern that conforms to a valid IP address.